# PHP Slim 2.X router call match method

Tags: php, slim

**PHPSlim version**: 2.4.3

I would like to match an string against php slim router to know to which route it matches. ¿Is that possible? I couldn't find any "match" method exposed.

Example:

```
<?php

$match = $router->match("/party/create");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slim already has a method for this:

`$this->app->router()->getMatchedRoutes($httpMethod, $url);`

More information:
https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/blob/2.x/Slim/Router.php#L104

Comment: I didn't notice that file, i was checking Slim.php since it has some route related methods... Thanks!